# D365 Online: Custom Entity Limit

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Can someone clarify if there is a documented limit on the number of custom entities that are available on a new organisation on D365 online?

I heard and seen numerous references to a ~300 entity limit but I can find any official documentation beyond this:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37177.dynamics-365-online-limitations.aspx

I have just spun up a trial instance and can see that there are 1500 entities available on this instance.  Have Microsoft increased this limit recently?

I understand that even with the lower limit it can be increased via support request but this would be a bottleneck in terms of spinning up test environments.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost answered your own question. :)

> Till CRM 2015 update 1, we had upper limit of 200 Workflows, 300 Dialogues and 300 Custom Entities. From CRM 2015 Update 1 onwards, the limit of workfows, dialogues and custom entities have been removed.
> In Dynamics 365 Online we can still see information related to custom entities which shows upper limit as 300. However this is more of indicative and there is no upper limit now.

[That 300 limit was there quite sometime](https://nishantrana.me/2016/11/16/resources-in-use-300-custom-entities-limit-in-dynamics-365-online/), now it’s showing 1500, this upper limit is an indicator and more of an arbitrary count from MS to give customers a ball park for estimation. Since it force you to reach out to them if your enterprise requirement is exceeding, they want to understand it. Moreover on-premise does not have any limitation other than SQL limits.

Also MS will add more entities based on your opt-in modules in your org. That being said, we can always reach out to  MS support for this limit to increase, moving to dedicated scale group, etc after technical evaluation.

> With Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) there is a limit to the number of entities you can create. You can find information about the maximum number in the Resources In Use page for your deployment. If you need more custom entities, contact Microsoft Dynamics 365 technical support. This upper limit can be adjusted.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/administering-dynamics-365/dn531137(v=crm.8)?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#limitations-on-creating-metadata-items)